# How to map multiple JsonProperty to a single variable?

Tags: java, jackson

I got a PrintType enum and I want to deserialize empty Strings as DEFAULT type like;

```
@JsonProperty("default", "")
DEFAULT
```

Is there any way to map multiple JsonProperty to a single variable?

```
My PrintType enum;

public enum PrintType{

    @JsonProperty("default")
    DEFAULT,


    ....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please note that `JsonProperty` is used to denote the names of properties, not their values. In this example, `DEFAULT` is an element of the enumeration, not its property/field/method, so this annotation would not be appropriate.

To deserialize an enum element from multiple possible values, you'll need to create a simple `JsonDeserializer` that will do the mapping. For example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PrintTypeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<PrintType> {

  private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_VALUES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("", "default"));

  @Override
  public PrintType deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    final String value = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
    if (DEFAULT_VALUES.contains(value)) {
      return PrintType.DEFAULT;
    }
    return PrintType.valueOf(value);
  }

}
```

To use this deserializer, either declare it on the `PrintType` field to be deserialized:

```
public class MyObj {

  @JsonProperty("print_type")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = PrintTypeDeserializer.class)
  private PrintType printType;

}
```

(But this would need to be duplicated if `PrintType` appears in different objects)

Or register the deserializer within the respective `ObjectMapper`:

```
private static ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
  final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
  module.addDeserializer(PrintType.class, new PrintTypeDeserializer());
  mapper.registerModule(module);
  return mapper;
}
```

Now, a short test case:

```
public enum PrintType {

  DEFAULT, TYPE_A, TYPE_B;

}

@Test
public void deserializeEnum() {
  final List<String> jsons = Arrays.asList(
      "{ \"print_type\": null }",
      "{ \"print_type\": \"\" }",
      "{ \"print_type\": \"default\" }",
      "{ \"print_type\": \"DEFAULT\" }",
      "{ \"print_type\": \"TYPE_A\" }",
      "{ \"print_type\": \"TYPE_B\" }"
  );

  final ObjectMapper mapper = initObjectMapper();

  jsons.stream().forEach(json -> {
    try {
      System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, MyObj.class));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  });

}

// output:
//  MyObj(printType=null)
//  MyObj(printType=DEFAULT)
//  MyObj(printType=DEFAULT)
//  MyObj(printType=DEFAULT)
//  MyObj(printType=TYPE_A)
//  MyObj(printType=TYPE_B)
```